# Squared sum of errors

Tags: regression, sums-of-squares

Why does $\mbox{SST} = \mbox{SSR} + \mbox{SSE}$ hold?

It is understandable that $\sqrt{\mbox{SST}} = \sqrt{\mbox{SSR}} + \sqrt{\mbox{SSE}}$ but how can $\mbox{SST} = \mbox{SSR} + \mbox{SSE}$ hold?
These are squared values.

Comment: It's not understandable to me that $\sqrt{\mbox{SST}} = \sqrt{\mbox{SSR}} + \sqrt{\mbox{SSE}}$ could be true. How does that follow?

Comment: Glen_b -- I agree. I think what OP must have meant was that $ y_i - \bar{y} = y_i - \hat{y}_i + \hat{y}_i - \bar{y} $

Comment: yeah i meant yi−y¯=yi−y^i+y^i−y¯   only

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

\begin{eqnarray*}
SST & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\bar{y})^{2}\\
 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}((y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})+(\hat{y}_{i}-\bar{y}))^{2}\\
 & = & \underset{SSE}{\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^{2}}}+\underset{SSR}{\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y}_{i}-\bar{y})^{2}}}+2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\bar{y}_{i})(\hat{y}_{i}-\bar{y}).
\end{eqnarray*}
It can be shown that $2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\bar{y}_{i})(\hat{y}_{i}-\bar{y})=0.$

Lets think about how to do that last step. First note that $\hat{y}_{i}=\hat{\beta}_{0}+\hat{\beta}_{1}x_{i}=\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}_{1}(x_{i}-\bar{x})$
and so $(\hat{y}_{i}-\bar{y})=\hat{\beta}_{1}(x_{i}-\bar{x})$. Furthermore,
we can write $(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})=(y_{i}-\bar{y})-\hat{\beta}_{1}(x_{i}-\bar{x}).$
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\bar{y}_{i})(\hat{y}_{i}-\bar{y}) & = & \hat{\beta}_{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})-\hat{\beta}_{1}^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}\\
 & = & \left(\dfrac{Q_{xy}}{Q_{xx}}\right)Q_{xy}-\left(\dfrac{Q_{xy}}{Q_{xx}}\right)^{2}Q_{xx}\\
 & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
 because $\hat{\beta}_{1}=Q_{xy}/Q_{xx}.$

Also I used the standard sum of square notation, e.g. $Q_{xx}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}$
etc

Comment: This is a little problematic to me, see:-